# Postgres index creation time

Tags: postgresql

Postgres is creating simple index more than 2 days. Where can I see a log, or something about status index creation? Before this situation I've created index couple times and it took about an hour or less. I have about 5.5m rows and execute next command:

```
CREATE INDEX collapse_url ON tablle (url, collapse)
```

Comment: First, check to see if the `CREATE INDEX` statement is actually being blocked by another process/transaction: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring.  Please update your post with your findings

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. The `CREATE INDEX` statement is waiting for a lock.

   You should be able to see that in the `pg_stat_activity` view.

   If that is your problem, end all concurrent long running transactions (e.g. using `pg_terminate_backend`).
2. The `CREATE INDEX` statement is truly taking very long (unlikely with a few million rows).

   In that case, you can speed up processing by increasing `maintenance_work_mem` *before* you create the index.

There have been relevant improvements in this area in recent versions:

- PostgreSQL v11 introduced parallel index builds.
- PostgreSQL v12 introduced the view `pg_stat_progress_create_index` to monitor the progress of `CREATE INDEX`.
- PostgreSQL v12 also introduced `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` to avoid a long `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table.